# Java: Elegant way to print out text to Console or Text file

Tags: java

i've a Java program that print out some text output. Actually my simple PrintOutput function is something like

```
System.out.println("some output");
```

But i would like to declare a variable

```
printonfile = true
```

to print my output to a text file if setted to true, or to screen (console) if setted to false.

How can i assign the out to a file instead to System.out avoiding to make something like

```
 if (printonfile) {
   myfile.out("some output");
 }
 else {
   System.out.println("some output");
 }
```

Is there a way to declare an "output" variable at the beginning of my function so i can assign it the standard output (console) or a text file ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at logging frameworks, seems to be the right solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `out` field of the System class is an instance of the `PrintStream` class; you can also construct a PrintStream object that outputs to a file.  So your idea of setting up the output location could work as follows

```
PrintStream myOut = null;
// Decide output method somehow
if(...) {
  myOut = System.out;
}
else {
  myOut = new PrintStream(new File("/path/to/a/file"));
}

// Use the PrintStream to write a message
myOut.println("Hello World");

// Tidy up at end
myOut.close();
```

Answer (score 10):

You've described a typical use case for the Strategy design pattern.

Create an interface `Printer`, make 2 implementations `ConsolePrinter` and `FilePrinter`, and use the correct one depending on the situation you have.

```
interface Printer {

   void print(String msg);
}

class ConsolePrinter implements Printer {

   public void print(String msg) {
      System.out.print(msg);
   }
}

class FilePrinter implements Printer {

   private final FileWriter fileWriter;

   public FilePrinter(File file) {
      this.fileWriter = new FileWriter(file); //here you should do some exceptions handling
   }

   public void print(String msg) {
      fileWriter.write(msg);   //here you should also care about exceptions
      fileWriter.flush();
   }
}

Printer chosenPrinter = printOnFile ? new FilePrinter(file) : new ConsolePrinter();
chosenPrinter.print("Hello");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
    PrintSream stream = printToFile ? 
                        new PrintStream(new File(filename)) 
                        : System.out;
```

Now you can use stream wherever you want without any changes.

Answer (score 3):

Look at a [logging library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_logging_framework) e.g. [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) or [java.util.logging](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) to give very detailed control of output.

Answer (score 0):

It will take a bit if time to properly set up, but log4j is definately worth a try if you want better/custom logging of your warnings, errors and general messages.